# Address parser in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv file containing addressId and address of the customers as below

| addressId | address |
| --- | --- |
| ADD001 | "123, Maccolm Street, Copenhagen, Denmark" |
| ADD002 | "384, East Avenue Street, New York, USA |

I want to parse the address column to get number, street, city and country. I am given initial code to build on to get the necessary output

```
object Address extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("CustomerAddress").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  case class AddressRawData(
                             addressId: String,
                             address: String
                           )

  case class AddressData(
                          addressId: String,
                          address: String,
                          number: Option[Int],
                          road: Option[String],
                          city: Option[String],
                          country: Option[String]
                        )

 def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData]): Seq[AddressData] = {
    unparsedAddress.map(address => {
      val split = address.address.split(", ")

      address.copy(
        number = Some(split(0).toInt),
        road = Some(split(1)),
        city = Some(split(2)),
        country = Some(split(3))
      )
    }
    )
  }
  val addressDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("src/main/resources/address_data.csv")

  val addressDS: Dataset[AddressRawData] = addressDF.as[AddressRawData]
}
```

I assume that I need to use addressParser function to parse my addressDS information. However, the parameter to the function is of type Seq. I am not sure how should I convert addressDS as an input to function to parse the raw data. some form of guidance to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an answer to the question please if it was solved

Answer (score 0):

```
def addressParser(addressId: String, customerId: String, address: String): AddressData = {
    val split = address.split(", ")
    AddressData(addressId, customerId, address, Some(split(0).toInt), Some(split(1)), Some(split(2)), Some(split(3)))
  }

  spark.udf.register("addressParserUDF", addressParser _)

  val groupedAddressDataDS = addressDF
    .selectExpr("customerId", "addressParserUDF(addressId, customerId, address) as parsedAddress")
    .groupBy("customerId")
    .agg(Map("parsedAddress" -> "collect_set"))
    .withColumnRenamed("collect_set(parsedAddress)", "address")
    .select($"customerId", $"address")

  // Join customerAccountDS and groupedAddressDataDS by customerId
  val customerDocumentDS = customerAccountDS
    .join(groupedAddressDataDS, Seq("customerId"), "left_outer")
    .selectExpr("customerId", "forename", "surname", "accounts", "address")
    .as[CustomerDocument]
```

You need to define the addressParser method to include addressId, customerId along with the address. Then register the addressParser function as a UDF and use it to parse the address, addressId and customerId which should give you the ideal output